# Why 'What was your most difficult bug hunt' is an edge question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question

I learned a lot reading '[What was your most difficult bug hunt](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/what-was-your-most-difficult-bug-hunt-and-how-did-you-find-it-and-kill-it)' I'm sure it will help me and others (who I plan to narrate some of the stories to) will benefit too. can we please re open it and keep it so others may add a few more ? I know it can be used as an excuse for more discussion style, but this one is a real gem and helpful in more than a general way. There are specific learning points there:

1. bug might be due to a particular area in a other wise common area on
   screen (top scorer, I wont mention the particular term used there as
   I do not like it)
2. the most simplest things like int and short can cause issues
3. know your API/ flush

Am sure others can add more. Let us not lose the chance of others adding more great answers, the next bug just might not be found as yet or is being made as you read this.

Answer (score 4):

Although interesting, this type of question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. There are [quality guidelines for questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) that define what types of questions are good, and this doesn't fit those criteria. Specifically, questions like this, where every answer is equally correct and the question is open-ended, are not a good fit for this format.

Consider starting a discussion in [our chat room, The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) or creating a new chat room for this purpose if you want to have this discussion inside the Stack Exchange network. Otherwise, perhaps a more discussion-oriented service would be more appropriate.

Comment: Oh well it was worth a try. Wish there was once place for all the other stuff. But I still wish there was some leeway in the rules. Even science and nature is full of exceptions not sure what you guys hope to gain by killing good exceptions. Just losing good content and making us hunt in more than 1 place

Comment: this question looks like an excellent candidate for historical lock, does it? As far as I can tell, answers given more than sufficiently "meet Jeff Atwood's 3rd rule..." mentioned in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/historical-lock/info (_"Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?"_)

Comment: @gnat It's a little low on the view count considering it's going on 3 years old, but perhaps. I'll flag it and have someone else take a look. I wouldn't be opposed to a historical lock, though.

Comment: @gnat & Thomas: Why lock it? Is it in danger of getting deleted? If not, why not just let it be as it is?

Comment: @YannisRizos it is in danger of ...collecting upvotes. Question is _really_ good, as are many answers (though not a good fit for SE Q&A). It naturally attracts upvotes, along with making readers think, _"since this one is highly voted and getting more of it, why shouldn't I try asking / answering similar questions?"_ That's why I for one would much prefer to see a notice "please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here"

Comment: @gnat Well, that might be, but the lock's purpose is not to protect a question from getting upvotes. And it already has a notice telling people that it's not a suitable question for the site, it's the notice that starts with the big bad "closed".

Comment: @YannisRizos my understanding is, lock's purpose is 1) keeping good content and 2) protecting _readers_ from asking similar questions. Does it fit here? As for _big bad "closed"_, give me a break. If an inexperienced reader sees a question at +30 and answer at +70, how much attention are they going to pay to that notice? how much would they be tempted to try to repeat it? Every new upvote it gets, only adds to that temptation

Comment: @gnat If it's not about to be deleted, or reopened, I honestly don't see why we should lock it. You posted a comment yesterday on one of the answers, asking for an update on some broken links. Neither your comment nor the update would have been possible if the question was locked. Also, if people fail to notice it's closed and only notice the score, they'll also fail to notice the historical lock.

Comment: @YannisRizos who told you it's not going to be reopened? 5 votes aren't that difficult to obtain. As for fixing something in the locked answers, well in cases when it's _really_ important, this can be provided by a dedicated, new question (which could be also a good fit for SE Q&A model), I've been through that in the past

Comment: @gnat Ping me when it's at 4 re-open votes and I'll take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

To put simply, it was **Not Constructive**.

As stated in the [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), questions that are subjective in which each answer is equally valid is usually not a good fit for the site. Stack Exchange frowns upon subjective questions; it's just not a good fit for this style of Q&A.